# Can't let my script keep trying with different proxies from a list until there is a valid response

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've written a script in python in combination with selenium to fetch different posts from a website using rotation of proxies. The script only tries once and then quits. What I wish to do now is let my script keep trying with different proxies in order to get a valid response until the list are exhausted.

I thought my implementation is right but the script tries once and then quits. As it doesn't throw any error, I can't let the script keep trying even if there is a `try/except` clause.

```
import random
from selenium import webdriver
from random import choice

link = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping'

proxies = ['103.110.37.244:36022', '180.254.218.229:8080', '110.74.197.207:50632', '1.20.101.95:49001']

def start_script():
    random.shuffle(proxies)
    proxy_url = choice(proxies)
    print("implementing:",proxy_url)
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument(f'--proxy-server={proxy_url}')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    return driver

def get_links(url):
    driver = start_script()
    try:
        driver.get(url)
        items = [item.get_attribute("href") for item in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".summary .question-hyperlink")]
        for item in items:
            print(item)

    except Exception:
        driver.quit()
        get_links(url)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_links(link)
```

As I get some questions in the comments whether `items` variable returns empty value, I decided to provide a working code which proves that the variable in reality contains desired list.

```
from selenium import webdriver

link = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping'

def get_links(url):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(url)
    items = [item.get_attribute("href") for item in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".summary .question-hyperlink")]
    for item in items:
        print(item)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_links(link)
```

PS `The proxy list are the placeholders. They are not working ones.`

***How can I let my script keep trying with different proxies to fetch a valid response until the list are exhausted?***

Comment: For one thing, your blanket `except Exception:` statement is likely hiding the key to fixing at least some of the possible problems by not telling you what the error might be. One other issue I see is that you shuffle and choose proxies at random, so there's nothing preventing your script form choosing the same proxy twice in a row

Comment: I defined this portion `except Exception:` only to show that I've tried as the script is not throwing any error either without that clause. As for your second question: yes, the script can pick the same proxy twice. Once the script is capable of throwing any exception, I can spot the bad proxy and then kick it out.

Comment: so how would you know the proxy is faulty ? wound items be an empty list ?

Comment: would be very useful if you would supply a list of currently working proxies. That is keeping me from looking at your problem right now.

Comment: Do you want to go until the list is exhausted or until you get a successful result? Do you want to break out of processing once a proxy has worked or would you still process the other proxies?

Comment: Until I get a successful result @drxl.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will do what you need. I shuffled the proxies and then loop through them. If a good result is found, it processes the items and breaks out of the loop and is done. If anything goes wrong or it finds no result, it just tries the next proxy in the list.

```
import random
from selenium import webdriver
from random import choice

link = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping'

proxies = ['103.110.37.244:36022', '180.254.218.229:8080', '110.74.197.207:50632', '1.20.101.95:49001']

def start_script(proxy_url):
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument(f'--proxy-server={proxy_url}')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    return driver

def get_links(url):
    random.shuffle(proxies)
    for proxy in proxies:
        driver = start_script(proxy)
        try:
            driver.get(url)
            print('Url {} retrieved, get elements'.format(url))
            elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".summary .question-hyperlink")
            print('Selected elements, check for None')
            if elements is not None:
                print('Found {} elements'.format(len(elements)))
                items = [item.get_attribute("href") for item in elements]
                if items is not None and len(items) > 0:
                    for item in items:
                        print(item)
                    break;
        except Exception:
            print('Proxy {} failed, trying next'.format(proxy))
        finally:
            driver.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_links(link)
```

Comment: This is the same problem I was having with my above script. The thing is your script never goes past this `driver.get(url)` line. If it was then I could see the outcome of this `print('Proxy {} failed, trying next'.format(proxy))` line in the console.

Comment: maybe your issue is with the driver.find_elements_by_css_selector. If that call is returning None for some reason, your list comprehension will fail. Are you able to debug through the code? I put some extra checking code in and some print statements to give you a better idea where it is failing. I'm thinking all of the proxies are just not working and you are getting nothing when you do the driver.get. This does not throw an error, it just gives you nothing and the elements will be an empty array.

Comment: It looks like your working code is not using a proxy. When I test this, I use no proxy and I get values for elements and items and everything works well. When I use the proxy, I get nothing. It just seems to do nothing and there are no errors. Since this is what you are also seeing, I'm guessing there is something wrong with the proxies. Your original code also does not loop, so it will only ever try one random proxy and be done - failure or no. Maybe you just have a list of proxies that aren't working.